# Extracting a number to push to an array

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm still trying to get this music game to work.  My intention is to achieve this:when the pad is pressed on the sampler, i want its id to be pushed to an array called player1Array.  The problems is that when i try and push the padSounds following a click event, the a tag, a # and the number get pushed and i just need the number.  I tried parseInt but kept getting NaN.  Here is the code:

```js
var player1array = [];
var padSounds = $("a");

padSounds.on("click", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var text = $(this).text();
  var number = parseInt(text, 10);
  player1array.push(number);
  console.log(player1array);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="sampler">
  <a href="#" id="1">One</a>
  <a href="#" id="2">Two</a>
  <a href="#" id="3">Three</a>
  <a href="#" id="4">Four</a>
  <a href="#" id="5">Five</a>
  <a href="#" id="6">Six</a>
  <a href="#" id="7">Seven</a>
  <a href="#" id="8">Eight</a>
  <a href="#" id="9">Nine</a>
  <a href="#" id="10">Ten</a>
  <a href="#" id="11">Eleven</a>
  <a href="#" id="12">Twelve</a>
  <a href="#" id="13">Thirteen</a>
  <a href="#" id="14">Fourteen</a>
  <a href="#" id="15">Fifteen</a>
  <a href="#" id="16">Sixteen</a>
</div>
```

I also tried a for each and the console ended up logging every single pad.

Hope i've been clear and thanks in advance

Comment: Can you post the relevant HTML too?

Comment: https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/javascript-debugging

Comment: if we can the corresponding html , it cn b helpfull

Comment: <div id="sampler">
          <a href="#" id="1"></a>
          <a href="#" id="2"></a>
          <a href="#" id="3"></a>
          <a href="#" id="4"></a>
          <a href="#" id="5"></a>
          <a href="#" id="6"></a>
          <a href="#" id="7"></a>
          <a href="#" id="8"></a>
          <a href="#" id="9"></a>
          <a href="#" id="10"></a>
          <a href="#" id="11"></a>
          <a href="#" id="12"></a>
          <a href="#" id="13"></a>
          <a href="#" id="14"></a>
          <a href="#" id="15"></a>
          <a href="#" id="16"></a>
        </div>

Comment: sorry that didn't really work

Comment: is there a better way for me to display the html?

Comment: edit the question and add it as code as you have the javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace this line

```
$(this).text();
```

With

```
this.id;
```

http://api.jquery.com/text/